# Android Download manager not downloading zip file

Tags: android, zip, android-download-manager

I have made Android application that download zip file from server using Android Download Manager class and then uncompress the file and store that into SD card on pictures folder. On some of the phones.

The zip file is not downloading and download manager progress bar never show progress even if I keep it for hours. Whereas on other phones this works perfectly.

The file size is 40 MB. Is there any known limitation of Android Download Manager or in case of .zip files?

Comment: This is certainly something you can find out with a little research  and debugging of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a variation of (using another class for unzipping, but since the issue here is related to downloading, i am suggesting it) this class for purposes of downloading (the file name retains specific implementation, but it is just a matter of renaming accordingly...). The work() method of this class can be called from within the run method of a Runnable object for parallel threading as inferred from the initial comment:

```
package com.package;

/* 

   This class is intended to download file filtering purpose and suffix from the server.   
   IMPORTANT:This is intended to be instantiated within a separate thread (i.e., != UI Thread)

*/

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

final class FileDownloader
{
    // Declaring a the maximum buffer size
    private static final int MAXIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    // Declaring static final byte fields for coding the status
    protected static final byte ISDOWNLOADING = 0;
    protected static final byte ERROROCCURRED = 1;
    protected static final byte DOWNLOADISCOMPLETE = 2;

    // Declaring a private URL field for storing the file for downloading
    private java.net.URL url = null;
    // Declaring a private int field for storing the file size in bytes
    private int filesize;
    // Declaring a private int field for storing the amount of downloaded bytes
    private int bytesDownloaded;
    // Declaring a private byte field for storing the current status of the download
    private byte currentStatus;

    // A private static final string for storing the server contents location
    private static final String SERVER = "https://server.com/zipfiles/";
    // Declaring a private field for storing the caller context, used for defining
    // the path for saving files
    private android.content.Context callerContext = null;

    // The following rule is going to be applied for distributing purpose and their contents:
    // 'purpose.x.zip' zip file to store the folders of the the x purpose_id and its inherent
    // structure
    private static final String PURPOSE= "purpose";
    private String x = null;
    private static final String SUFFIX = "zip";

    // The remote file to be downloaded is going to be [stringed as]:
    // SERVER + PURPOSE + "." + ((String.valueOf(x)).trim()) + "." + suffix
    private String remoteFile = null;

    // Defining a private static final File field for storing the purposes' contents within it.
    // Specifically, this is being designed to be:
    // java.io.File seekingRegisteredUserFolder =
    // new java.io.File(callerContext.getFilesDir(), "RegisteredUser");
    private final java.io.File seekingRegisteredUserFolder;

    // The class constructor. The constructor depends on constructing elements for downloading
    // the remoteFile respective to the element_ [cf. constructor parameter] under consideration,
    // viz.:
    protected FileDownloader(final String x_, final android.content.Context callerContext_)

            throws
            java.net.MalformedURLException,
            java.io.FileNotFoundException,
            java.lang.SecurityException

    {

        this.x = x_;
        this.remoteFile = SERVER + PURPOSE + "." + ((String.valueOf(this.x)).trim()) + "." + SUFFIX;

        int parsedW = 0;
        try
        {
            parsedW = Integer.parseInt(x_);
        }
        catch (Exception throwableThrownParsingW)
        {
            throw new java.net.MalformedURLException();
        }
        // Implementation specific
        if (parsedW < 1)
        {
            throw new java.net.MalformedURLException();
        }

        this.callerContext = callerContext_;
        this.seekingRegisteredUserFolder = new java.io.File((this.callerContext).getFilesDir(), "RegisteredUser");
        if (!((this.seekingRegisteredUserFolder).exists()))
        {
            throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException();
        }
        this.url = new java.net.URL(this.remoteFile);
        this.filesize = -1;
        this.bytesDownloaded = 0;
        this.currentStatus = ISDOWNLOADING;        
    }

    // Begins the file download. This is to be called under an object of this class instantiation
    boolean work()
    {
        final java.io.RandomAccessFile[] randomAccessFile = {null};
        final java.io.InputStream[] inputStream = {null};
        final java.io.File[] purpose = {null};

        try
        {
            purpose[0] = new java.io.File(seekingRegisteredUserFolder, (PURPOSE + "." + x + "." + SUFFIX));

            // Opens a connection to the URL via ssl

            final javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection[] connection = {null};
            connection[0] = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            // Defines the file part to download
            connection[0].setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + bytesDownloaded + "-");

            // Connects to the server
            connection[0].connect();

            // The response code must be within the 200 range
            if ((connection[0].getResponseCode() / 100) != 2)
            {
                currentStatus = ERROROCCURRED;
            }

            // Inferring the validity of the content size
            final int[] contentLength = {0};
            contentLength[0] = connection[0].getContentLength();
            if (contentLength[0] < 1)
            {
                currentStatus = ERROROCCURRED;
            }

            // Configuring the download size, case not yet configured
            if (filesize == -1)
            {
                filesize = contentLength[0];
            }

            // Opens the file, seeking its final
            randomAccessFile[0] = new java.io.RandomAccessFile(purpose[0], "rw");
            randomAccessFile[0].seek(bytesDownloaded);

            inputStream[0] = connection[0].getInputStream();

            while (currentStatus == ISDOWNLOADING)
            {
                // Defines the buffer according to the left amount of file to complete
                byte[] byteBuffer = null;
                if ((filesize - bytesDownloaded) > MAXIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE)
                {
                    byteBuffer = new byte[MAXIMUM_BUFFER_SIZE];
                }
                else
                {
                    byteBuffer = new byte[filesize - bytesDownloaded];
                }

                // Reads from server to the buffer
                int read = inputStream[0].read(byteBuffer);
                if (read == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Writes from buffer to file
                randomAccessFile[0].write(byteBuffer, 0, read);
                bytesDownloaded += read;
            }

            // Changing the status for complete since this point of code has been reached
            if (currentStatus == ISDOWNLOADING)
            {
                currentStatus = DOWNLOADISCOMPLETE;
            }

        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception connectionException)
        {
            currentStatus = ERROROCCURRED;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Closes the [RandomAccessFile] file
            if (randomAccessFile[0] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    randomAccessFile[0].close();
                }
                catch (java.lang.Exception closingFileException)
                {
                    currentStatus = ERROROCCURRED;
                }
            }

            if (inputStream[0] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    inputStream[0].close();
                }
                catch (java.lang.Exception closingConnectionException)
                {
                    currentStatus = ERROROCCURRED;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((currentStatus == DOWNLOADISCOMPLETE) && (purpose[0] != null) &&
            (purpose[0]).isFile() && (purpose[0].length() > 0) && (purpose[0].length() == filesize))
        {
            ((AppCompatActivity) callerContext).runOnUiThread
            (
                 new Runnable()
                 {
                     @Override
                     public final void run()
                     {
                          Toast.makeText(callerContext, "Downloaded: " + remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.indexOf(SERVER) + SERVER.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     }
                 }
            );

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```